# how to put an image upon a image in a li which (on hover) changes its z-index

Tags: css, z-index, html-lists

I have the following image in a li:

```
  <ul class="columns">
    <li><a href="some url"><img src="images/layouts/test.png" alt="" /></a> </li>
</ul>
```

My css looks like this:

```
ul.columns li img {
        position: relative;
        }

    ul.columns li:hover img{
        z-index: 999;
        }
```

What does it do:
When I hover my mouse over the image (test.png), the image get's a new z-index. This is needed to keep the image visible (a div is displayed on hover and the image should stay on top of it). This all works great.

Now I want to have a image in the top right corner (displaying an X, so lets call it x.png) over the normal image. How to do this? Making the test.png a background image is not an option. Played around with some classes and z-index but the second image always appears besides the test.png image. I think I do something wrong with the CSS, but I don't know how to z-index the second image in a li

I have this atm:

```
<ul class="columns">
    <li><a href="some url"><img src="images/layouts/test.png" alt="" /> <img class="x" src="images/x.png" alt="" /></a> </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
 ul.columns li img,
 ul.columns li {
    position: relative; /* so the close image is relatively 
                           positioned inside <li> */
    z-index : 1;
 }

 ul.columns li img + img {
    position: absolute;
    top     : 0;
    right   : 0;
    display : none;
 }

 ul.columns li:hover img { z-index: 999; }
 ul.columns li:hover img + img  { z-index : 1000; display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're trying to do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/GvWaZ/1/

You should use `position:relative` in your link, so when you use `right:0` style, the image goes to the right of the anchor.

```
.columns a {
    position:relative;
}
.colums a .x {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Also, refer to the close second image by its class `x`, like in this css style:

```
.columns a:hover .x {
    z-index: 999;
    /* class="x" specific hover styles */
}
```